# FFMPEG - How to get supported code list for specific file or Container for enumeration

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to find supported codec for specific file like(.avi,.mp4, .mov) for enumeration and encoding.
I Was enable to find list of codec support for which container. Using ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

That information isn't easily available. For each muxer (container) you have to examine the source code.  The best way to is to locate the exception handling routine which will throw an error when a codec is not supported and observe and note which cases are allowed. Also, see the stream tagging routines and and take note which tags are supported.